# jQuery Dialog not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

It seems like one of my two dialog box won't show up, although the second one does when asked to. Both are inside a `$.get()` success function. It is as shown:

```
$.getJSON('addCategory.php', {'ordre':ordre,'nom':nom}, function(data) 
                            {
                                console.log(data.result);

                                    $('div id="Dialog_Feedback2">Une catégorie porte déjà ce nom ou cet ordre!</div>').dialog(
                                    {
                                        autoOpen:false,
                                        title:'Une erreur est survenue!',
                                        width:300,
                                        height:'auto',
                                        resizable: false,
                                        show:"slide",
                                        modal:true,
                                        buttons:{
                                            "OK" : function()
                                            {
                                                $( this ).remove();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                    $('<div id="Dialog_Feedback">L\'ajout a été effectué avec succès!</div>').dialog({
                                        autoOpen:false,
                                        title:'Catégorie ajoutée!',
                                        width:400,
                                        height:'auto',
                                        resizable:false,
                                        modal:true,
                                        buttons:{
                                            "Ok": function()
                                            {
                                                $(this).remove();
                                                window.location.reload();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }); 
                                    if(data.result =="true")
                                    {
                                        console.log("NO!");
                                        $('#Dialog_Feedback').dialog("open");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        console.log("Yeah!");
                                        $('#Dialog_Feedback2').dialog("open");

                                    }                           
                                }

                            );
                        }
```

Here is what I see in the console:

`false`

`Yeah!`

But the `#Dialog_Feedback2` won't show up. When it returns `true`, the other dialog appears correctly.

Why won't the second dialog show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very simple problem, all you have to do is correctly write the div tag, you are missing the beginning carat. So the line

```
$('div id="Dialog_Feedback2">Une catégorie porte déjà ce nom ou cet ordre</div>').dialog(`
```

Should begin with

```
$('<d
```

not just

```
$('d
```

This should give you your desired operation.

Comment: Most of my problems seem to rely on small mistakes. Thank you for your help sir, those 2000 lines make me blind ^^. *accepted in 2 minutes*

Comment: Just a tip, next time try setting up a test case in [jsFiddle](jsFiddle.net), that's what I did, I got rid of the AJAX wrapper, and just set the data value to be either true or false, it really helps for troubleshooting.